# Raytracing in python

Tags: python, raytracing

I am trying to do ray tracing implementation using python but i am getting a white and black image for output. the shape is correct but the the image lacks colors. I am new to this type of programming so i dont really know what is causing the problem here.

My code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot


def vector_nomalization(vector): #function to normalize a vector
    return vector / np.linalg.norm(vector)


def intersection_with_sphere(center, radius, origin, direction_vector): #function to detect intersection between sphere and ray
    b = 2 * np.dot(direction_vector, origin - center)
    c = np.linalg.norm(origin - center) ** 2 - radius ** 2 # die länge von (origin - center)^2  - radius
    delta = b **2 - 4 * c
    if delta > 0:
        t1 = (-b +np.sqrt(delta))/2
        t2 = (-b - np.sqrt(delta))/2
        if t1 > 0 and t2 > 0:
            return min(t1,t2) #distance from origin to the nearest intersection point
    return None


def closest_intersection(spheres, origin, direction): #find closest sphere that intersects with our ray
    distances = [intersection_with_sphere(sphere['center'], sphere['radius'], origin, direction) for sphere in spheres]
    closest_sphere = None
    min_distance = np.inf
    for index, distance in enumerate(distances):
        if distance and distance < min_distance:
            min_distance = distance
            closest_sphere = spheres[index]
    return closest_sphere, min_distance


def reflection_ray(vector, axis):
    return vector - 2 * np.dot(vector, axis) * axis


spheres =[
    { 'center': np.array([-0.2, 0, -1]), 'radius': 0.7, 'ambient': np.array([0.1, 0, 0]), 'Diffuse': np.array([0.7, 0, 0]), 'specular': np.array([1, 1, 1]), 'shininess': 100, 'reflection': 0.5 },
    { 'center': np.array([0.1, -0.3, 0]), 'radius': 0.1, 'ambient': np.array([0.1, 0, 0.1]), 'Diffuse': np.array([0.7, 0, 0.7]), 'specular': np.array([1, 1, 1]), 'shininess': 100, 'reflection': 0.5 },
    { 'center': np.array([-0.3, 0, 0]), 'radius': 0.15, 'ambient': np.array([0, 0.1, 0]), 'Diffuse': np.array([0, 0.6, 0]), 'specular': np.array([1, 1, 1]), 'shininess': 100, 'reflection': 0.5 },
    { 'center': np.array([0, -9000, 0]), 'radius': 9000 - 0.7, 'ambient': np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1]), 'Diffuse': np.array([0.6, 0.6, 0.6]), 'specular': np.array([1, 1, 1]), 'shininess': 100, 'reflection': 0.5}
]

light = {'position': np.array([5, 5, 5]), 'ambient': np.array([1, 1, 1]), 'Diffuse': np.array([1, 1, 1]), 'specular': np.array([1, 1, 1])}


width = 300
height = 200

max_depth = 3

camera = np.array([0, 0, 1])
ratio = float(width) / height  # ratio = image width / image height
screen = (
-1, 1 / ratio, 1, -1 / ratio)  # screen defined by 4 numbers: left,top,right,bottom (x coordinate ranges from -1 to 1)

image = np.zeros((height, width, 3))

for i, y in enumerate(np.linspace(screen[1], screen[3], height)):  # splits the screen into width and height points in x and y directions
    for j, x in enumerate(np.linspace(screen[0], screen[2], width)):
        pixel = np.array([x, y, 0])
        origin = camera
        direction_vector = vector_nomalization(pixel - origin) #oder auch ray

        color = np.zeros((3))
        reflection = 1

        for k in range(max_depth):

            #intersection?
            closest_sphere, min_distance = closest_intersection(spheres, origin, direction_vector)
            if closest_sphere is None:
                break

            #intersectionpoint between ray and closest sphere
            intersection = origin + min_distance * direction_vector

            normalized_to_surface = vector_nomalization(intersection - closest_sphere['center'])
            shifted_point = intersection + 1e-5 * normalized_to_surface
            lights_intersection = vector_nomalization(light['position'] - shifted_point)

            _, min_distance = closest_intersection(spheres, shifted_point, lights_intersection)
            lights_intersection_distance = np.linalg.norm(light['position']-intersection)
            shadowed = min_distance < lights_intersection_distance
            if shadowed:
                break

            #RGB
            illumination = np.zeros((3))

            #diffuse
            illumination += closest_sphere['Diffuse'] * light['Diffuse'] * np.dot(lights_intersection,    
            normalized_to_surface)

            #specular
            camera_intersection = vector_nomalization(camera - intersection)

            camera_light = vector_nomalization(lights_intersection + camera_intersection)

            illumination += closest_sphere['specular'] * light['specular'] * np.dot(normalized_to_surface,                                
            camera_light)

            color += reflection + illumination
            reflection *= closest_sphere['reflection']

            origin = shifted_point
            direction_vector = reflection_ray(direction_vector,normalized_to_surface)

        image[i, j] = np.clip(color, 0, 1)
    print("progress: %d/%d" % (i + 1, height))


    plt.imsave('image.png', image)
```

This is what i am getting
[image: My output]

and this is how its supposed to look like
[image: What its supposed to look like]

Answer (score 0):

Why you're getting only white (and black) is because of your 'reflection'

you have hard-coded `reflection = 1` on line 66 - The devil's in the details, as they say!

And then on line 103: `color += reflection + illumination`. As reflection starts at 1 for every new iteration in the for j, x loop, you're making sure here that color is at least 1, 1, 1. So that's why you're getting white.